# How should I assigned the same value to two different keys in this Perl hash?

Tags: perl

When I have 2 data structures meaning the same thing, ex:

```
$c->req->cookies->{app1} = $c->req->cookies->{general};
$c->req->cookies->{app2} = $c->req->cookies->{general};
```

Can I write:

```
( $c->req->cookies->{app1}, $c->req->cookies->{app2} ) = $c->req->cookies->{general};
```

?

Also, Can I write:

```
   $c->req->cookies->{app1} =  $c->req->cookies->{app2 } = $c->req->cookies->{general};
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second form is possible and some people use it frequently

```
$x = $y = $z;
```

The first form does not do what you need. It only assings the value to the first variable.

```
($x, $y) = $z;
```

You need two member list on the right hand side as well:

```
($x, $y) = ($z) x 2;
```

**Update:**
In your case, you can use the `x` operator only if the methods involved return the same values for both invocations, otherwise, you can use

```
($x, $y) = map $obj->method, 1, 2;
```

Comment: also: `$c->req->cookies->{$_}= $c->req->cookies->{general} for (qw(app1 app2));`

Comment: Another solution is to use slices: `@{$c->req->cookies}{qw/app1 app2/} = ($c->req->cookies->{general})x2`. That would make this Law of Demeter-violation slightly more bearable.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, there are many ways to do it. For example, you could also use a hash slice:

```
@{ $c->req->cookies }{qw( app1 app2 )}
```

But, I would recommend a lack of originality:

```
my $cookies = $c->req->cookies;
my $general_cookie = $cookies->{general};
$cookies->{$_} = $general_cookie for qw(app1 app2);
```

which makes the code more readable, doesn't create new data structures, and reduces complex dereferencing as much as possible.